# Add any number of whitespaces to file

Tags: sed

I have a plain text file:

```
line1_text
line2_text
```

I need to add a number of whitespaces between the two lines.
Adding 10 whitespaces is easy.

But say I need to add 10000 whitespaces, how would I achieve that using sed?

P.S. This is for experimental purposes

Comment: Show how you added 10 lines programmatically! and does it have to be with sed ?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There undoubtedly is a `sed` method to do this but, since `sed` does not have any natural understanding of arithmetic, it is not a natural choice for this problem.  By contrast, `awk` understands arithmetic and can readily, for example, print an empty line `n` times for any integer value of `n`.

As an example, consider this input file:

```
$ cat infile
line1_text
line2_text
```

This code will add as many blank lines as you like before any line that contains the string `line2_text`:

```
$ awk -v n=5 '/line2_text/{for (i=1;i<=n;i++)print""} 1' infile
line1_text





line2_text
```

If you want 10,000 blank lines instead of 5, then replace `n=5` with `n=10000`.

#### How it works

- `-v n=5`

  This defines an awk variable `n` with value `5`.
- `/line2_text/{for (i=1;i<=n;i++)print""}`

  Every time that a line matches the regex `line2_text`, then a `for` loop is performed with prints an empty line `n` times.
- `1`

  This is awk's shorthand for print-the-line and it causes every line from input to be printed to the output.

Comment: thankswould a lot of whitespaces be considered different than a line by an interpreter?

Comment: @scandalous That would depend what the interpreter is and what you are trying to get it to do.  It would be very easy to print blanks in place of newlines.  You decide what you want and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/line1_text/{x;s/.*/ /;:a;ta;s/ /&\n/10000;tb;s/^[^\n]*/&&/;ta;:b;s/\n.*//;x;G}' file
```

This appends the hold space to the first line. The hold space is manipulated to hold the required number of spaces by a looping mechanism based on powers of 2. This may produce more than necessary and the remainder are chopped off using a linefeed as a delimiter.

To change spaces to newlines, use:

```
sed -r '/line1_text/{x;s/.*/ /;:a;ta;s/ /\n&/10000;tb;s/^[^\n]*/&&/;ta;:b;s/\n.*//;s/ /\n/g;x;G}' file
```

In essence the same can be achieved using this (however it is very slow for large numbers):

```
sed -r '/line1_text/{x;:a;/ {20}/bb;s/^/ /;ta;:b;x;G}' file
```